# Why does my page not scroll to the top when clicked?

Tags: html

The line is:
`<li class="nav-item"><a class="active nav-link me-lg-3" href="#">About me</a></li>`

But for some reason the page does not scroll to the top of the page.

E.g. when I'm at the bottom of the page and I click the About me in the navbar, the page should scroll up.

Comment: post the code in a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is a link that targets an ID on the  element:

```
 <html id="top">
  <body>
     <!-- the entire document -->
     <a href="#top">Jump to top of page</a>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I thought of that but then it says <www.site.com/#top>

and that's something I don't want,

unless there's a way to hide that #top as well?